# Twilio link shortening and SSL certificate: One or more domains inside SAN cert is not verified in the organisation SID

Tags: ssl, twilio

I renewed a SSL certificate with RapidSSL to use with Twilio Link Shortener. The whole thing was working properly until yesterday where I tried to update the certificate, a few days in advance from the expiry.

I downloaded the .pem certificate from RapidSSL and the private key. As the private key was not in PKCS#8 format, I had to convert it, like this:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in rsa.key -out pkcs8.key -nocrypt
```

Now, when trying to upload the certificate and the private key to twilio, I have the following error message:

```
One or more domains inside SAN cert is not verified in the organisation SID
```

I looked into the certificate file like this:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -noout -text | grep "Subject: CN"
```

It gives me:

```
Subject: CN=thedomain.com
```

Which domain is obviously validated in the organisation SID.
I tried to re upload the former certificate as it will expire only in 10 days (to avoid production disruption) and disaster, I get the same error message.

Am I doing something wrong ? Can anyone make sense of this error message ? I contacted twill's support with no luck so far (they are us based, I'm in the EU, I'd like to avoid wasting a week of back and forth due to tz)

Thanks in advance for the much appreciated help

Comment: Not programming or development, but: [SAN = Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) is an extension separate from and not technically linked to the Subject field, although CABforum rules say Subject.CommonName _should_ be consistent with some entry in SAN. To look at SAN in OpenSSL 1.1.1 up use `-noout -ext subjectAltName`; otherwise use `-text` as you did and `grep -A1 'X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:'`

Comment: For Subject Alternative name I have thedomain.com and www.thedomain.com. Only thedomain.com is verified in twilio. Trying to verify www.thedomain.com fails as there is no need to verify subdomains... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out it was an issue on Twilio's side. Their support just fixed it. I uploaded again the exact same files and all went well...